# & in XmlDocument.AppendChild

Tags: .net, xml

I am trying to write a string out to an xml node

```
strConverted = strConverted + "&#60;sup&#62;" + Mid(strConvertMe, intC, 1) + "&#60;/sup&#62;"

Doc = New XmlDocument()
Me.Root.AppendChild(h.BuildXML())
```

produces XML like this (in part):
String that was converted `&amp;#60;sup&amp;#62;2&amp;#60;/sup&amp;#62;` more string stuff

see how the & in the string gets turned into &amp

anyone have any ideas how to stop this?

Comment: What is "h"?  What does BuildXML do? How is the strConverted then used?  How is Doc used?  Is Doc related to Me.Root in some way?  As you can see your question is full of questions of its own.

Answer (score 1):

If the `&` is part of a string, it *should* be converted into `&amp;`. That's part of XML escaping.

What are you actually trying to represent?

It would also help if you could provide more useful sample code - currently you've got three statements which aren't directly linked at all, using a completely different set of variables each time.

I strongly suspect that you shouldn't be building up your `strConverted` as a string in the first place - any XML generation code which contains "manual" tags is begging to be rewritten to use the API more idiomatically.

If you can give us more indication of what you're trying to achieve, we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Trying to embed <sup></sup> in the XML so that that content will be superscripted. 
&#60;sup&#62;2&#60;/sup#&62; renders the number 2 properly as superscript. 

There is some code to create an XML document object and assign strConverted to one of its nodes. Works correctly 99.9% of the time. When I try to write an & character; it is converted to &amp. Don't want to re-model the whole process and use a different strategy. Just want to stop amp from being added. Do I need to escape the character? How in VB.NET?



&amp#60;sup&amp#62;&amp#60;/sup&amp#62; renders as <sup>2</sup> on the page

Comment: The previous comment got all messed up

Comment: &#60;sup&#62;2&#60;/sup#&62; renders the number 2 properly as superscript

&amp#60;sup&amp#62;&amp#60;/sup&amp#62; renders as <sup>2</sup> on the page

Comment: There is some code to create an XML document object and assign strConverted to one of its nodes. It works correctly 99.9% of the time. When I try to write an & character; it is converted to &amp. I don't want to re-model the whole process and use a different strategy. Just want to stop amp from being added. Do I need to escape the character? How do I do that in VB.NET?

Comment: I think you're confused about the difference between text nodes and elements. If you want to nest one element within another, you should do so using the API. If you want to embed a text string within the XML, just do that instead - and let the escaping happen. When you read back the text later, it will be unescaped again.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your string from getting parsed using the CData directive:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<converted>" +
            "<![CDATA[" +
             strConverted +
            "]]>" +
            "</converted>");
```

Comment: I though of that but for some reason my boss doesn't want me to do that. :wtf

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add a `sup` element to your XML output, just create a `sup` element:

```
XmlElement sup = doc.CreateElement("sup");
sup.InnerText = value;
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(sup);
```